# Kafka Hdfs 2 Sink connector not able to write on hdfs

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

Following is my kafka connector json file:

```
curl -s -k -X POST  http://cpnode.local.lan:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
"name":"jdbc-Hdfs2-Sink-Connector",
"config":{
"tasks.max":"1",
"batch.size":"1000",
"batch.max.rows":"1000",
"hdfs.poll.interval.ms":"500",
"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
"hdfs.url":"hdfs://hadoopnode.local.lan:9000",
"topics":"BookList2",
"flush.size":"1",
"confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers":"cpnode.local.lan:9092",
"confluent.topic.replication.factor":"1",
"value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://cpnode.local.lan:8081",
"key.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"key.converter.schemas.enable":"true",
"key.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://cpnode.local.lan:8081"
}
}' | jq '.'
```

When I try to use this connector I get following error:

```
{
  "name": "jdbc-Hdfs2-Sink-Connector",
  "connector": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "worker_id": "192.168.1.153:8083"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "state": "FAILED",
      "worker_id": "192.168.1.153:8083",
      "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=cp-user, access=WRITE, inode=\"/\":hadoop:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
```

I have tried `export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs` and also
hadoop configuration hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.permissions</name>
   <value>false</value>
</property>
```

But I want a solution without compromising security.

**cp-user** is the name of my confluent platform user...
Both the confluent and hdfs are on different VMs

Thanks in advance....

Comment: PS: I am using hadoop-2.9.2 and confluent platform 5.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user: user=**cp-user**,

Is trying to `access=WRITE`,

To the location `inode=\"/\"`

Which has user/group ownership of **hadoop:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x**

---

Possible Solutions (non-overlapping):

1. Change `cp-user` to `hadoop` (I assume you are using the Docker container? If so, refer to the `user` directive ***of Docker***. Otherwise, `export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hadoop`)
2. Create and add `cp-user` Unix account to the NameNodes of the Hadoop cluster and all datanodes
3. Use Kerberos

Comment: Thank you for quick reply.....I am using centos7 on vmplayer.....I tried the export command on terminal of cp-user and even added it to the ~/.bashrc file of cp-user.....both didn't work......can you please give me the steps to do that....sorry for annoying you with trivial questions but I am fairly new at this.....